# ML.NET: MLContext random seed does not make it deterministic

Tags: f#, random-seed, ml.net

Update: the problem persists in Microsoft.ML 1.5.0.

---

I just implemented the first ML.NET API [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis) in F# and then initialised the `MLContext` like so:

```
let mlContext = MLContext (Nullable<int> 5)
```

I take it that this should cause the results to be the same between runs, but the results change. Am I doing something wrong?

The only other element I can find that invokes randomness is `TrainTestSplit`, but when I set the seed for that also in the same way, I still get changing results.

Comment: There was [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/4752) that mentions the seed. Have you tried with the latest preview version to see if that is any better?

Comment: Thanks, @Jon. Yes, I'm using Microsoft.ML 1.5.0-preview2.